# How to pass additional jars to LogStash classpath

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have 'narrowed' installation of LogStash that has removed ElasticSearch jars from vendor folder. However, these jars are available on the machine but in different folder. I found in documentation for LS 1.0.14 (http://logstash.net/docs/1.0.14/installation) that I could run

```
CLASSPATH=$(ls /opt/elasticsearch/lib/*.jar | tr '\n' ':') /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

to load ElasticSearch jars from elsewhere. However, in LogStash 1.4.0 this no longer works for me. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Copy additional jars to `/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars`

Can be done while building docker image

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.11.0

COPY ./lib/ /usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/jars
```

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch output plugin in Logstash 1.4 looks for the elastiscsearch libs in `/opt/logstash/vendor/jar/elasticsearch*/lib` (see [environment.rb](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/master/lib/logstash/environment.rb) )

So you could link your existing elasticsearch libs there (provided they are of compatible version):

```
cd /opt/logstash/vendor/jar
# make sure no old elastic libraries are here!
ls elasticsearch*
# rm -fr elasticsearch*
mkdir elasticsearch-local
ln -s /opt/elasticsearch/lib elasticsearch-local/lib
```

I didn't test this, as the approach I use is to fully rebuild logstash with the required elasticsearch library version updated in the Makefile.